# Unhook jQuery from WooCommerce via `functions.php`?

Tags: theme-development, functions, jquery, debug

So I am using the http://woothemes.com/woocommerce/ plugin for eCommerce and it's registering jQuery local and conflicting with my default jQuery call from Google CDN.

It took a long time but I isolated the issue to the following lines of code within `woocommerce.php`:

```
    $suffix = defined('SCRIPT_DEBUG') && SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '' : '.min';
    $lightbox_en = (get_option('woocommerce_enable_lightbox')=='yes') ? true : false;
    $chosen_en = (get_option('woocommerce_enable_chosen')=='yes') ? true : false;
    $jquery_ui_en = (get_option('woocommerce_enable_jquery_ui')=='yes') ? true : false;
    $scripts_position = (get_option('woocommerce_scripts_position') == 'yes') ? true : false;

    // Woocommerce.min.js is minified and contains woocommerce_plugins
    wp_enqueue_script( 'woocommerce', $this->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/woocommerce'.$suffix.'.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', $scripts_position );
    if ( defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'woocommerce_plugins', $this->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/woocommerce_plugins'.$suffix.'.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', $scripts_position );
    }
```

Deleting them cancels out the duplicate jQuery call which is causing me all my headaches.  I have the following in `functions.php` to dequeue jQuery from the header, but for some reason, it persistsand refuses to go away! :/  Any ideas how to kill the local jQuery call from within `functions.php`?  Is there something wrong with my code? :

```
// dequeue jquery from header

function theme_slug_dequeue_header_jquery() {
     wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_header', 'theme_slug_dequeue_header_jquery', 11 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it looks like your calling jquery wrong. You should *always* use wp_enqueue_script, otherwise your asking for conflicts. Don't call it manually.

The lines you pasted in from WooCommerce don't load jquery directly - they load it by setting the dependencies for the other scripts. WordPress handles the rest.

If you want to use jQuery from a CDN, deregister it and re-register it with the CDN version. Rather than paste you the code I'll direct you to the following example which explains how:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/replace-default-wordpress-jquery-script-with-google-library/

Comment: Can one of you state the steps to take to get this problem solved? I'm still a little unclear. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem and stumble into this thread.

My issue was that WooCommerce 2.0.5 was registering jQuery by himself and that was breaking my own jQuery scripts, creating a conflict with my functions.php deregister/register/enqueue process.

After several attempts I noticed that I wasn't including the jQuery version in my function. After specifically adding it, the problem was solved.

This is what woocommerce/woocommerce.php does (line 1214):

```
public function check_jquery() {
    global $wp_scripts;

    // Enforce minimum version of jQuery
    if ( isset( $wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver ) && $wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver < '1.7' ) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js', array(), '1.7' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}
```

And this is how I override it in my functions.php file

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 
        'jquery', 
        'http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js',
        false, 
        '1.9.1' // IMPORTANT: declare jQuery version
        );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}  

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Hope this could help someone else :)

Comment: Updating the version number totally fixed this for me as well. Those version numbers are there for a reason....

Answer (score -1):

Use this code to dequeue jQuery from any plugin, assuming that is enqueues the script using the wp_enqueue_script() function.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_jquery', 999999 );

function dequeue_jquery() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

The priority of 999999 causes the function to be called last, hopefully, in most cases.

Comment: The currently shipped version of jQuery (with WP core) is 1.8.x. Your recommendation will break. Maybe you want to edit your answer and include the version from the registered script array.